# Migrate a ASP.NET web service from http to https. How to create a SSL certificate that works in test environment on IIS 7.5?

Tags: https, asp.net, security-certificate, iis7, web-services

I have a question regarding a web service, `http` and `https`. First of all, there is a quite similar question with an accepted answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828555/http-and-https-web-service). Like the questioner on SO, I have a simple working `http://` web service. Now, my company wants to go to `https://` for security reasons.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7828607/1079093) on SO states that

> "You will need to change the config file in any client applications
>   that consume your service to the new URL.
>
> Your web service application should not require any changes. IIS will
>   handle the transport encryption with the SSL certificate."

I am very new to SSL (and `https`) an want to verify this in my isolated test environment (Windows Server 2008 R2 + IIS 7.5 + WLAN) before I deploy anything to production. My server application is a **ASP.NET web service**, my consumers are both **Android** and **iOS** clients.I need to create a "valid" test certificate that works with both server and clients.

I have tried to "Create Self-Signed Certificate" in IIS and bind it to the current site but I have not got it to work. How can I create a "valid" test certificate for my isolated experimental environment?

Answer (score 1):

When I do testing with security certificates, I often use the real certificate on the test machine.   I configure the test machine with the real host name.   Then I use my */etc/hosts* (or *hosts.txt*) file to point the real domain name to the test box for testing a client.

Doing this bypasses the need for generating certificates and making sure that all test clients can accept self-signed certificates.